# Error while implementing reverse geocoding with C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am trying to implement the reverse geocoding with visual studio using C#. But i could not handle the exception "**Argument out of range exception**".

**CODE:**

```
ReverseGeocodeQuery reverseGeocode = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
reverseGeocode.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(47.608, -122.337);
reverseGeocode.QueryCompleted += reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted;
reverseGeocode.QueryAsync();

private void reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted(object sender,
 QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
{
   MapAddress geoAddress = e.Result[0].Information.Address;

   if (e.Error == null && e.Result.Count > 0)
   {
       MapAddress address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
       MessageBox.Show(address.Country);
   }
}
```

**The exception shown is:**
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Kindly help me with the proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are expecting e.Result (an array) to have values when it might not, so when you try to access the first element (e.Result[0]), it fails.

The weird thing is, you are accessing e.Result[0] to make a variable you don't even use.

Change your code as follows and you won't receive the error:

```
private void reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
{    
   if (e.Error == null && e.Result != null && e.Result.Count > 0)
   {
       MapAddress address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
       MessageBox.Show(address.Country);
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, the error is resolved. But, nothing happens when reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted is triggered. I want to get the current user location (i.e, country). Please help me in  resolving this problem too.

Comment: Create a new question for your next problem, as your main problem is fixed.